# Does dodging have invincibility frames?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

When dodging, does it have any invincibility frames(you cannot be hurt during certain "frames" of the dodge)?

Do different weapons have a different amount of frames?(if they have invincibility in the first place)

where are these frames (if any)? start of the dodge? or towards the end?

Comment: It's not frames, I don't think, but a (super) short timer.  Which can be extended with the Evasion armor skill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, dodging does give a small number of invincibility frames. I believe the number is around 2 or 3? All weapons have the same number of invincibility frames. The armor skill Evasion increases how many invincibility frames you get.

In previous games, Evasion increased the number of invincibility frames in the following manner:

- +1: 8 frames
- +2: 10 frames

In MH4U, you can get Evasion +3, but I'm not quite sure how many more invincibility frames it gives you.

Comment: As a MH4U Evade Lancer, Evasion +3 makes the entire evade invincible. It's actually quite ridiculous how well I'm doing considering how mis-timed my evades have been, yet I'm barely getting touched.

Comment: Maybe you could mention the superman dive has more frames (and takes you further) than a roll. I'm not sure if DB's dash and Lance/GL's sidestep have more invuln. frames or if they simply take less time so invuln. frames are a higher percentage of the move - do you know?

Answer (score 2):

expanding on Yuuki answer:
at evade +1 you get around 1/4 of a sec invincibility
at evade +2 you get 1/3 of a sec
at evade +3 you get around a bit more of 1/2 of a sec

note that this is only when you roll, or side step when using bow/lance. and this happens only at the beginning-mid of the roll/sidestep.

it is kind of broken, since the sidestep is faster than a roll, and you can do a second sidestep right after finishing the first one, sidestepping will clearly show that you have evade+3 as you will be almost all the time of the sidestep invincible if you sidestep fast enough.

Comment: Sidesteps are faster, yes, but they're also *shorter*.  I'm not sure you can actually do more than one sidestep before finishing the first one; I main Gunlance, and I don't see that happening.  Maybe for Lance?

Comment: you are correct, I meant to say right after.

Comment: Also applies to DB's demon/archdemon dash dodge.

Comment: IIRC the time for evasions are 0.2s/0.333s/0.4s (for +0, +1, and +2), though I don't know how much +3 gives